# How can I solve this String length problem?

Tags: javascript, string, function, numbers, return

I am learning JavaScript and I came across a problem in learnjavascript.online

"String length
Complete the function getNameLength such that it returns the length of the name that it receives."

Tests (0/2)
returns a number 
returns the correct length

I did it this way but it didn't work

```
/**
 * @param {string} name
 */
function getNameLength(name){
    return name;
}

console.log(getNameLength('John'.length));
console.log(getNameLength('Argentina!'.length));
console.log(getNameLength('Macedonia'.length));
```

And the return was this

Tests (0 / 2)
returns a number.
Expected returned value to be equal to number but got string.

returns the correct length.
Expected getNameLength("Hey!") to be equal to 4 but got Hey!.

How do I solve this?

Comment: The logic which obtains the length of the string should go inside your function body. So you should pass in your string instead, and then return the length from within your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calculating the length within the function rather than in the console log? This ensures that all of the logic is first completed within the function before it is returned in the console log. Your function expects the string name, but you are passing name.length

```js
function getNameLength(name){
    return name.length;
}

console.log(getNameLength('John'));
console.log(getNameLength('Argentina!'));
console.log(getNameLength('Macedonia'));
```

Comment: Got it, I thought I should use Length on each console, your way worked, thanks